# Which customer ate which Food (Correct Join?)

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, common-table-expression

I was given a question in an interview like this

Restaurants in the area serve various food to customers. As long as customers keep showing up to a restaurant regularly, that restaurant will keep serving the same dish. If no customers visit a restaurant for more than 3 days, then that restaurant will serve a new type of food starting when the next customer visits. Unfortunately, some ingredients were contaminated and caused a few customers to suffer from food poisoning. The restaurants know which food was affected and are now trying to figure out which customers were affected. The restaurants keep their own catalog of customers, so there is no guarantee that a customer has the same customer ID at each restaurant. All restaurants serve food in the same order. Figure out which customer ate which food.

Sample Data:

Restaurant:

```
restaurant_id   customer_id visit_date
1         1     2020-01-01
2         1     2020-01-01
1         2     2020-01-03
3         1     2020-01-04
2         2     2020-01-14
3         1     2020-01-11
2         3     2020-01-14
```

Food:

```
food_id food_name
1       Spaghetti
2       Chicken and Rice
3        Tacos
```

Desired:

```
Restaurant  Customer    Visit   Food
1   1   2020-01-01  Spaghetti
2   1   2020-01-01  Spaghetti
1   2   2020-01-03  Spaghetti
3   1   2020-01-04  Spaghetti
2   2   2020-01-10  Chicken and Rice
3   1   2020-01-11  Chicken and Rice
2   3   2020-01-14  Tacos
```

I wrote the query as :

```
select r.*,f.food_name 
from restaurant  r left join 
food f on 
f.food_id=r.customer_id
```

But it didn't give me the desired result. Can some please guide me to desired result.

Comment: *Desired:* Impossible - the tables have no needed data. *`f.food_id=r.customer_id`* You think that WHO eats and WHAT he eats is the same???

Comment: This has been asked before

Comment: You need to build a relation b/w customer and food tables probably many to many

Comment: @Strawberry : Can you please show me where it has been asked?

Comment: Just type the question's keywords into the SO search bar

Comment: I have just checked it , there is no help

Comment: In the sample data, you don't have a visit on 1/10, but in the desired results you do. Also, based on the data, it would appear that only 2 of the 3 foods would be served. There's no need to serve the 3rd food based on the date of visits. I'm guessing the sample data is wrong here.